# The polynomial $x^{2k} + 1 + (x+1)^{2k}$ is not divisible by $x^2 + x +1$. Find value of $k$ such that it belongs to natural numbers.

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

I did some progress by doing this-

I thought if it would be a factor, then

$x^2 +x +1 = 0 $

$x+1=-x^2$

Putting this in the expression,
$$x^{4k}+x^{2k}+1$$
Then I tried to solve it further, but I am stuck here...

Comment: Between this and [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3553710/let-x-13-divides-px1-and-x13-divides-px-1-find-the-polynomi) it looks like you are just posting your homework here for us to do for you.

Comment: Lulu , I just registered today here . And I had some doubts in polynomials chapter of my Olympiad book , so I was asking them here ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^{2k}+(x+1)^{2k}+1\equiv x^{2k}+(x^2)^{2k}+1=x^{4k}+x^{2k}+1\equiv0$$ for any $k$, which is not divisible by $3$.

If $k$ is divisible by $3$, so since $x^3\equiv1$, we obtain:
$$x^{4k}+x^{2k}+1\equiv3.$$

Can you end it now?

Comment: @Aayush If $k$ is divisible by $3$ we see that $x^{4k}+x^{2k}+1=\left(x^3\right)^{\frac{4k}{3}}+\left(x^3\right)^{\frac{2k}{3}}+1\equiv1+1+1=3.$

Comment: Pls explain your step where you told what would happen if it is a multiple of 3

Comment: @Aayush because $x^3-1=(x+1)(x^2+x+1)\equiv0.$

Comment: Oh sorry I read wrong , thanks for your help

Comment: @Aayush You are welcome!